# linq2db.MySql - Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type.. Where not found

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Visual studio 2017 C#
I am attempting to implement Linq2db for MySQL and being a Linq newbie am having a bit of trouble. I am trying to follow the example from GitHub linq2db using a simple two column table (maillist) – integers list and client_id which together is the primary key.
I have installed linq2db.MySql from nuget including linq2db and linq2db.t4models. Using “conventional” methods I can process the database so the connection works. This is what I have done so far.

My App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7"/>
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
                <add name="MyWinBroker" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=winbroker;Uid=root;Pwd=DeValk@123!;charset=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
            </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

POCO Class:

```
using LinqToDB.Mapping;
using LinqToDB;

[Table(Name = "maillist")]
public class Mailing
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    public int List { get; set; }
    public int Client_id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "list"), NotNull]
    public int MailList { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "client_id"), NotNull]
    public int Client { get; set; }
}
public class DbWinbroker : LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection
{
    public DbWinbroker() : base("MyWinbroker") { }
    public ITable<Mailing> Mailing { get { return GetTable<Mailing>(); } }

}
```

The Query

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using FileHelpers;
using FileHelpers.Events;
using Itenso.TimePeriod;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using LinqToDB;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static List<Mailing> All()
{
    using (var db = new DbWinbroker())
    {
        var query = from p in db.Mailing  
                    where p.MailList < 99
                    select p;
        return query.ToList();
     }
}
```

This won’t compile I get the red squiggly line under db.Mailing in the query and the error:

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'ITable<Form1.Mailing>'. 'Where' not found.
```

If I remove the where clause I then get two different errors.
Maybe I do need to include a reference but which?

```
The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.
'T' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have seen many posts regarding variations of this error but I still don’t understand it.
Any help would be appreciated.

TIA,
Gerry.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops! I forgot using system.Linq;

Sorry if I caused anyone any trouble.